# Increase speedup with OpenMP and reductions

Tags: c, openmp, pragma

I would increase speedup of these code with OpenMP.

```
for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
   for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
     sum_c += c[j];
   c[i] = sum_c + W[i];
   sum_c = 0;
}
```

I try with these solution

```
for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
   #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NTHREADS) reduction(+:sum_c)
   for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
     sum_c += c[j];
   c[i] = sum_c + W[i];
   sum_c = 0;
}
```

but I increase speedup only for

```
length=100000
```

Are there any better solutions? The code can be rewritten.

Comment: I guess for smaller `length` the overhead of managing the openMP threads is more than the benefit from it.

Comment: What is NTHREADS commonly for your use case(s)? And what architecture are you running this on (cores and cache size can matter; cache size perhaps more of vectorization done by the compiler)?

Comment: You can compile with optimisation -O3 and check the assembly to see if it vectorises (I suspect not). You can try to get OpenMP to vectorise it with #pragma omp simd before the inner loop. Alternatively, you can manually vectorise it using simd intrinsics.

Comment: In fact can't you eliminate the inner loop entirely?

Comment: This loop is indeed not needed. It is a huge waste of resource to compute it for every `i`. You can just update `sum_c` based on the modification of `c[i]` (computing delta). The resulting code will run in `O(n)` rather than `O(n²)`. The sum just need to be computed once, not `length` times. Golden rule of optimization : focusing on improving algorithms before trying to use more resources.

Comment: By the way, specifying `num_threads(NTHREADS)` is considered as a bad practice. It is better to tweak the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. This is far more flexible. Developers are notoriously bad at guessing the best number of threads (not to mention it tends to change over time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeating work a lot using a inner loop. The same result can be obtained by the following single loop.

```
sum_c = 0;
for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
{
   c[i] = sum_c + W[i];
   sum_c += c[i];
}
```

Comment: This in turn can be parallelized using a [`scan` directive](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu45.html). But I don't know if it makes any sense in terms of performance. Probably not for `length` being smaller than 100k.